# vim: How do I map <F5> to prepend a timestamp to the current word the cursor is on?

Tags: vim

In vim, when I press F5, I want it to add a timestamp immediately before the word that the cursor is on.

For example: If I have a file with the following text:

```
the quick brown
fox jumps
over the lazy
dog
```

and I press F5 while my cursor is on any of the letters in the word `jumps`, then I want it to add a timestamp immediately before the word `jumps`, so that it looks like below:

```
the quick brown
fox [ 12:34:50 20190531 ] jumps
over the lazy
dog
```

If I move my cursor to any of the letters in the word `dog` and press F5, then I want it to look like this:

```
the quick brown
fox [ 12:34:50 20190531 ] jumps
over the lazy
[ 12:34:58 20190531 ] dog
```

I currently have these lines in my .vimrc that will add a timestamp wherever the cursor is, but I want it to be a little smarter and add the timestamp immediately before the current word that the cursor is on:

```
nmap <F5> i<C-R>=strftime("[ %H:%M:%S %Y%m%d ] ")<CR>
imap <F5> <C-R>=strftime("[ %H:%M:%S %Y%m%d ] ")<CR>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The safest option is to use visual mode here:

```
nnoremap <F5> viWo<Esc>"=strftime("[ %H:%M:%S %Y%m%d ] ")<CR>gP
inoremap <F5> <C-O>viWo<Esc><C-R>=strftime("[ %H:%M:%S %Y%m%d ] ")<CR>
```

That is, go visual mode, select inner WORD, go to the start of selection, end visual mode, put strftime().

Answer (score 1):

Try these:

```
nnoremap <F5> T<space>i<C-r>=strftime("[ %H:%M:%S %Y%m%d ] ")<cr><esc>
inoremap <F5> <C-o>T<space><C-r>=strftime("[ %H:%M:%S %Y%m%d ] ")<cr>
```

This uses `T<space>` to move 'till (`t`/`T`) the next space, backwards due to the capital `T`. An explicit space () would work as well, used `<space>` to highlight.

Comment: This doesnt work well if the word is at the beginning of the line

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Absolutely, did't consider that case. I would suggest to use Matt's solution.